# Поврежденный файл при передаче через сокет

Tags: java, сокет, docx

Я пишу сервер обработки документов и мне понадобилось передать docx документ, однако после завершения передачи клиенту приходит поврежденный файл который невозможно открыть. Файл на сервере в порядке. Тестировал передачу с обычными txt файлами, они приходят нормально.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Серверная часть:

```
import generator.DocumentWorker;

import java.io.*;
import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ServerSocket server = null;
        DocumentWorker documentWorker = new DocumentWorker();
        try {
            server = new ServerSocket(4050);
            System.out.println("Сокет сервера запущен");
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Невозможно запустить сервер: "+e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        //Тестовый клиент
        Client client666 = new Client();
        client666.start();
        while(true) {
            try {
                Socket client = server.accept();
                DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(client.getInputStream());
                OutputStream responce = client.getOutputStream();
                File file = new File("test.docx");
                FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(file);
                InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
                String str = (String) dis.readUTF();
                if(str.equals("getreceipt")) {
                    System.out.println("Задание получено с IP-адреса "+client.getLocalAddress());
                    //Отправляем файл
                    documentWorker.generateReceipt("100500", "19.04.2020", "Имя компании").write(fos);
                    fos.close();
                    int count;
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[8192];
                    while ((count = in.read(buffer)) > 0)
                    {
                        responce.write(buffer, 0, count);
                    }
                    System.out.println("Задание выполнено");
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Возникла критическая ошибка: " + e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Клиентская часть:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

public class Client extends Thread {
    public void run() {
        DataOutputStream request = null;
        System.out.println("Запуск клиентской части обработчика документов");
        try (Socket socket = new Socket("localhost", 4050)) {
            System.out.println("Подключено к серверу обработки документов");
            request = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
            request.writeUTF("getreceipt");
            DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
            byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
            System.out.println(bytes[1]);
            in.read(bytes);
            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("clientfile.docx");
            fos.write(bytes);
            System.out.println("Документ получен");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Возникла критическая ошибка: " + e);
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DataInputStream.read возвращает кол-во байт, которое оно по факту прочитало. Но Ваш код игнорирует этот факт и просто потом пишет 8кб в файл. Поэтому, код записи должен быть где то таким

```
System.out.println("Подключено к серверу обработки документов");
request = new DataOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
request.writeUTF("getreceipt");
DataInputStream in = new DataInputStream(new 
BufferedInputStream(socket.getInputStream()));
byte[] bytes = new byte[8192];
System.out.println(bytes[1]);
int real_len = in.read(bytes);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("clientfile.docx");
fos.write(bytes, 0, real_len);
```

А текстовый документ отработал, потому что текстовый редактор просто проигнорировал нулевые символы.

Да, и этот код не сможет принять файл больше 8кб.